# Debugger console doesnt display error log when my app crashes in android studio, displays an error instead

Tags: android, debugging, error-logging

I recently created a `jni folder` in my android studio for my fonts and ever since i created that folder my debugger has not been functioning well.

When my app crashes, the **debugger console** displays this error instead

```
05/10 09:38:44: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.test | com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Waiting for application to come online: com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.test | com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Waiting for application to come online: com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.test | com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Waiting for application to come online: com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.test | com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Waiting for application to come online: com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug.test | com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Connecting to com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration
$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/lldb-server | run-as com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb/bin/lldb-server && chmod 700 /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb/bin/lldb-server'
$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh | run-as com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh && chmod 700 /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh'
Starting LLDB server: /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug/lldb unix-abstract /com.cinehub.aljem.cinemahubug-0 platform-1525934330030.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
Debugger attached to process 22052

Process finished with exit code 9
```

please help, thanks in advance

Comment: The error the is 'Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration'